# How do I change the anchor of RectTransform to change the width of a panel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a game with sprinting mechanics. I want this to be displayed like this using panels: (Where the green is the available sprint and the red is the depleted sprint)

[image: Sprint]

**I've done this using the following code:**

```cs
if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("s") || Input.GetKey("d"))
{
    walking = true;
}
else
{
    walking = false;
    if (!(energy == 100))
    {
        energy += 1f;
        energyBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(energy * 3, 40);

    }
}

if (Input.GetKey("r") && energy > 0)
{
    speed = 16f;
    if (walking)
    {
        energy -= 2;
        energyBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(energy * 3, 40);
    }
}
else
{
    speed = 8f;
}
```

Although this produces  a result like this:

[image: Sprint]

Any way to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution which involves changing the x of the panel.

```cs
if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("s") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            walking = true;
        }
        else
        {
            walking = false;
            if (!(energy == 100))
            {
                energy += 1f;
                energyBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(energy * 3, 40);
                energyBar.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(energy * 1.5f + 10, 150);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("r") && energy > 0)
        {
            speed = 16f;
            if (walking)
            {
                energy -= 2;
                energyBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(energy * 3, 40);
                energyBar.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(energy * 1.5f + 10, 150);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 8f;
        }
```

I declare a Rect variable: `Rect energyPos;`
And constantly updating a component: `energyPos = energyBar.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;`

Thank you to those who have tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

Simply select the according UI element and in the Inspector of the RectTransform set it's anchor to the left

[image]

[image]

Make sure to hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. That makes it also apply the anchor and position accordingly.

If you don't you would have to set the `Pivot x` and the `position x` both to `0` manually.

---

Alternatively - and in my eyes the better option - you could use an `Image` with Image type [`Filled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.Type.Filled.html) and fill method [`Horizontal`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.FillMethod.html)(should be the default).

Then from code you only set it's [`fillAmount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html) to a value `0` to `1`.

This way you don't have to bother with the position, anchors and size at all ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response but the top answer doesn't work. These are my settings: https://prnt.sc/ufb4i7

Comment: Maybe doesnt work because the pivot in x is in 0.5 put in 0 to make the pivot of the image to the left side and the position in x has to be 0 @AlphaZetta

Comment: @AlphaZetta try holding down `CTRL + SHIFT` and then press on the option again. This will do basically what Mario said

Comment: Another thing this will not work without a sprite in the Image component

Comment: @Mario you now refer to the second option, right? The first should also work without one

Comment: @derHugo but doesnt work because the Image dont let you change the Image type if you dont have a sprite, i already test that approach

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this script to adapt to your needs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class FillBar : MonoBehaviour
{
public Image _imageFill;
private RectTransform _imageFillRectransform;
private RectTransform _parent;

private float parentWidth;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _imageFillRectransform = _imageFill.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    _parent = _imageFillRectransform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    parentWidth = _parent.sizeDelta.x;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        _imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta += Vector2.right * 1f;
        
        _imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(_imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta.x, 0f, parentWidth), _imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta.y);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta -= Vector2.right * 1f;

        _imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(_imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta.x, 0f, parentWidth), _imageFillRectransform.sizeDelta.y);
    }
}
}
```

[image: Check this is the setup in my example]